# Can we use google maps data in bing maps?

Tags: google-maps, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I am using GOOGLE map's Matrix API in Server side code to calculate distances between different points , as there is NO GOOGLE maps API exists for WindowsPhone 8 so I am using Bing maps for Windows phone Client side application.

Now there are two questions :

1. Can we use calculated data using GOOGLE Matrix API in Bing Maps? Is there any copy right issues doing so?
2. Is there any bing maps Api exists which can be used to calculate distances like Google's matrix api?

Comment: Are you asking about using [the Distance Matrix API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/)?  That says "Use of the Distance Matrix API must relate to the display of information on a Google Map"

Answer (score 2):

Terms of use of both platform (Google Maps and Bing Maps) does not allow to use the service result from a platform on another platform's control.

See:

- Google Maps (10.1.1 g)

> (g) No Use of Content without a Google Map. You must not use or
>   display the Content without a corresponding Google map, unless you are
>   explicitly permitted to do so in the Maps APIs Documentation, or
>   through written permission from Google. In any event, you must not use
>   or display the Content on or in conjunction with a non-Google map. For
>   example, you must not use geocodes obtained through the Service in
>   conjunction with a non-Google map. As another example, you must not
>   display Street View imagery alongside a non-Google map, but you may
>   display Street View imagery without a corresponding Google map because
>   the Maps APIs Documentation explicitly permits you to do so.

- Bing Maps for Enterprise (3.2 q)

> (q) Integrate road maps from the Services with road maps supplied by
>   any third party. You may not replace aerial imagery from the Services
>   with imagery supplied by any other mapping platform. Notwithstanding
>   the foregoing, you may overlay aerial imagery that you have the rights
>   to use, provided that such imagery does not substantially replace the
>   base aerial imagery provided by the Services. You may incorporate
>   various data layers of types not available through the Services, in
>   the Company Applications (for example, demographic or school location
>   data). You may combine or overlay Ordnance Survey's United Kingdom
>   mapping data or data derived from Ordnance Survey’s United Kingdom
>   mapping data (but not Ordnance Survey roads data) with the Services,
>   provided that you have procured all such rights to the Ordnance Survey
>   United Kingdom mapping data, that such use of the Ordnance Survey
>   United Kingdom mapping data with the Services is consistent with your
>   Ordnance Survey license, and that you indemnify Microsoft for such use
>   pursuant to Section 3.8.

In terms of licensing, you won't be able to display the Google Maps result on a Bing Maps control and the countrary.

Comment: Thanks Nicolas Boonaert, So Is there any alternative of Google Matrix Api in Bing Maps?

Comment: Right now there is no alternative to distance matrix in Bing Maps for Enterprise platform.

Comment: Update: Bing Maps now has a distance matrix: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/maps/distance-matrix